# Why doesnt anything show up when opening website in browser?

Tags: css, web, xhtml

Bear with me, i am very new to web programming.

here is my simple code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Carlton Banks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CLICK ON CARLTONS HEAD!</h1>
        <a href="http://youtu.be/zS1cLOIxsQ8" target="_blank">
            <img src="hey.jpg" alt="A picture" style="width:300px">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the extremly simple css file:

```
body{
    h1: green
}
```

When opening the site on a browsers nothing at all shows up, just this error message:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 7 at column 10: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using XHTML, all tags needs to be closed.

The link tag should have a slash at the end to close it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

The same for the image tag:

```
<img src="hey.jpg" alt="A picture" style="width:300px" />
```

The CSS is incorrect. I think that this is what you are trying to do:

```
body h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Ill make sure to accept this answer when i am able to. I have one question, why is the `h1` tag not green? Its still black.

Comment: @Jagd I still does not show green. I cant figure out why.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the entirety of your css file? Syntactical error aside, it may be a caching issue, so try hitting Ctrl + F5 to force a refresh of your css file. You could also make things easier on yourself since you're new to this, and just embed the css straight into your html page. <style type="text/css">h1 { color: green; }</style>

Comment: You would stick that style tag within the scope of head tag, so... <head><style type="text/css">...</style></head>